# How to get the type you get after derefencing another type?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I find at compile time what type do I get after dereferencing something?

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <class TIteratorToPointerContainer>
class Something
{
public:
    typedef /*the thing you get by dereferencing TIteratorToPointer*/ TPointer;
    typedef /*the thing you get by dereferencing TPointer*/           TValue;
};

int main()
{
    Something<
              typename std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> >::iterator 
              >::TPointer pointer;
                      // "pointer" is of type std::shared_ptr<int>
    Something< 
              typename std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> >::iterator 
              >::TValue value;
                    // "value" is of type int
    return 0;
}
```

I can use C++11 features.

EDIT from answers:

```
typedef typename TIteratorToPointerContainer::value_type TPointer;
typedef typename TPointer::element_type TValue;
```

works for `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> >` but not for `std::vector< int* >`.

Comment: `typename`? I think you mean `typedef` ☺.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class TIteratorToPointerContainer>
class Something
{
private:
     using TPointer_ = decltype( *std::declval<TIteratorToPointerContainer>() );
     using TValue_ = decltype( *std::declval<TPointer>() );
public:
    using TPointer = typename std::remove_reference<TPointer_> :: type;
    using TValue = typename std::remove_reference<TValue_> :: type;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like so I think

```
typedef TIteratorToPointerContainer::value_type TPointer
typedef delctype(*TPointer) TValue
```

EDIT:

Not sure if the above will compile but this should work

```
typedef TIteratorToPointerContainer::value_type TPointer
typedef TPointer::element_type TValue
```

DOUBLE-EDIT:

Yea I should try to compile before suggesting... http://ideone.com/ByEvXj

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template <class TIteratorToPointerContainer>
class Something
{
public:
    typedef typename TIteratorToPointerContainer::value_type TPointer;
    typedef typename TPointer::element_type        TValue;
};

int main()
{
    Something<
              typename std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> >::iterator 
              >::TPointer pointer;
                      // "pointer" is of type std::shared_ptr<int>
    Something< 
              typename std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> >::iterator 
              >::TValue value;
                    // "value" is of type int

  std::cout << "pointer-name = " << typeid(pointer).name() << endl;
  std::cout << "value-name = " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pointer-name = St10shared_ptrIiE
value-name = i
```

Comment: I was not able to get either to compile, the second example is missing `typename`

Answer (score 1):

Try: `decltype( *ptr )`. This should get you the type you're looking for.

If you don't have a pointer to manipulate you can do:

```
template <typename T>
struct RemovePtr
{
  typedef T type;
}

template <>
struct RemovePtr<T *>
{
  typedef T type;
}

RemovePtr<int *>::type i = 5; // should be of type int
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not have anything to serve as an argument to decltype. Maybe I do not understand you, please could you paste it in the code and post?

Comment: thank you but this works for built in pointers, but not for smart pointers :(

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Without a pointer, you could do `decltype(*std::declval<pointer_type>())`. (You might need a bit of `remove_reference` as well).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
typedef typename TIteratorToPointerContainer::value_type TPointer ;
typedef typename TPointer::element_type TValue ;
```

Comment: Thank you, please see EDIT of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need C++11. C++98 already has `std::iterator_traits` :

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<TIteratorToPointer>::value_type TPointer;
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<TPointer>::value_type           TValue;
```

The latter works because pointers too are iterators.